# Number of times a particular character appears in a string

Tags: sql-server

Is there MS SQL Server function that counts the number of times a particular character appears in a string?

Comment: This might help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/6bd2da08-af9e-4216-bec3-1e859415d800

Comment: Try the following similar SO question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144172/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-character-appears-in-a-sql-column)

Comment: Duplicate of SO [How do you count the number of occurrences of a certain substring in a SQL varchar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch) which is older and has more answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count instances of character in SQL Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860457/how-to-count-instances-of-character-in-sql-column)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you count the number of occurrences of a certain substring in a SQL varchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

There's no direct function for this, but you can do it with a replace:

```
declare @myvar varchar(20)
set @myvar = 'Hello World'

select len(@myvar) - len(replace(@myvar,'o',''))
```

Basically this tells you how many chars were removed, and therefore how many instances of it there were.

Extra:

The above can be extended to count the occurences of a multi-char string by dividing by the length of the string being searched for. For example:

```
declare @myvar varchar(max), @tocount varchar(20)
set @myvar = 'Hello World, Hello World'
set @tocount = 'lo'

select (len(@myvar) - len(replace(@myvar,@tocount,''))) / LEN(@tocount)
```

Comment: Maybe using DATALENGTH instead LEN would be better, because LEN returns the size of the the string trimmed.

Comment: Using DATALENGTH needs care, as it returns the size of data used to store the variable. For a varchar this is ok as the number of bytes to store the data is equal to the length of the string. However nvarchar uses 2 bytes for each character, so DATALENGTH would double the length reported. There are other factors that may also affect DATALENGTH. See [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Be advised the code solution for multi-char strings returns +1 when the sought after characters are at the end of the string. For example: set @myvar = 'lo Hello World, Hello World, lo lo' returns 6 instead of 5.

Comment: To clarify on the comment left by @Langston - this solution fails if replacing the final copy of the search pattern text results in trailing spaces. LEN ignores trailing spaces, so it may calculate the difference in characters incorrectly. The answer is fine otherwise, but needs this caveat to be added (as do most of the duplicated answers below).

Answer (score 26):

Look at the length of the string after replacing the sequence

```
declare @s varchar(10) = 'aabaacaa'
select len(@s) - len(replace(@s, 'a', ''))
>>6
```

Comment: very smart idea

Answer (score 24):

You can do that using `replace` and `len`.

Count number of `x` characters in `str`:

```
len(str) - len(replace(str, 'x', ''))
```

Answer (score 16):

Use this function begining from SQL SERVER 2016

```
Select Count(value) From STRING_SPLIT('AAA AAA AAA',' ');

-- Output : 3
```

> When This function used with count function it gives you how many
>   character  exists in string

Comment: That is not answering the question.  What the string_split() function is doing  is counting the number of words separated by a space ' '.  It does not count the number of characters in the string.  `Select Count(value) From STRING_SPLIT('A AA AAA',' ');` also gives an answer of 3.

Comment: If SQL server compatibility allows that, then this is the best answer. E.g. Select Count(value)-1 From STRING_SPLIT('Hello World','l') counts the number of letter "l" in the Text.

Answer (score 6):

try that :

```
declare @t nvarchar(max)
set @t='aaaa'

select len(@t)-len(replace(@t,'a',''))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it inline, but you have to be careful with spaces in the column data.  Better to use datalength()

```
SELECT 
  ColName, 
  DATALENGTH(ColName) -
  DATALENGTH(REPLACE(Col, 'A', '')) AS NumberOfLetterA
FROM ColName;
```

-OR-
Do the replace with 2 characters

```
SELECT 
  ColName, 
  -LEN(ColName)
  +LEN(REPLACE(Col, 'A', '><')) AS NumberOfLetterA
FROM ColName;
```

Answer (score 2):

It will count occurrences of a specific character

```
DECLARE @char NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(10) = 'o'
    SET @char = N'Hello World';
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@char)
     BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@char, @i, 1) = @search
            SET @counter += 1;

        SET @i += 1;
     END;

     SELECT @counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

function for sql server:

```
CREATE function NTSGetCinC(@Cadena nvarchar(4000), @UnChar nvarchar(100)) 
Returns int 

 as  

 begin 

 declare @t1 int 

 declare @t2 int 

 declare @t3 int 

 set @t1 = len(@Cadena) 

 set @t2 = len(replace(@Cadena,@UnChar,'')) 

 set @t3 = len(@UnChar) 


 return (@t1 - @t2)  / @t3 

 end
```

Code for visual basic and others:

```
Public Function NTSCuentaChars(Texto As String, CharAContar As String) As Long

NTSCuentaChars = (Len(Texto) - Len(Replace(Texto, CharAContar, ""))) / Len(CharAContar)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it is working perfectly.
I have create a sql function that accept two parameters, the first param is the long string that we want to search into it,and it can accept string length up to 1500 character(of course you can extend it or even change it to text datatype).
And the second parameter is the substring that we want to calculate the number of its occurance(its length is up to 200 character, of course you can change it to what your need). and the output is an integer, represent the number of frequency.....enjoy it.

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSubstringCount]
(
  @InputString nvarchar(1500),
  @SubString NVARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN 
        declare @K int , @StrLen int , @Count int , @SubStrLen int 
        set @SubStrLen = (select len(@SubString))
        set @Count = 0
        Set @k = 1
        set @StrLen =(select len(@InputString))
    While @K <= @StrLen
        Begin
            if ((select substring(@InputString, @K, @SubStrLen)) = @SubString)
                begin
                    if ((select CHARINDEX(@SubString ,@InputString)) > 0)
                        begin
                        set @Count = @Count +1
                        end
                end
                                Set @K=@k+1
        end
        return @Count
end
```