# Counting Occurrences of a Character in Records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with many columns and rows, each row has a date (Not the Key) and 24 columns representing the hour of the day. In each field there is a code (N,C,Y,CT etc). I want to know how many of each code exists in a specified day.

The code to generate the sample data is here:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails](
    [DD_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [A_ID] [int] NULL,
    [DD_Date] [date] NULL,
    [H0] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H1] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H2] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H3] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H4] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H5] [nvarchar](2) NULL,

    [H6] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H7] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H8] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H9] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H10] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H11] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H12] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H13] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H14] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H15] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H16] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H17] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H18] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H19] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H20] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H21] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H22] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H23] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [H24] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [AllocatedBlock] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Comments] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Overtime] [decimal](10, 3) NULL,
    [PBlock] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SBlock] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TBlock] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BlockName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [DD_UserID] [int] NULL,
    [Std_Start] [datetime] NULL,
    [STd_End] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_DutyDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DD_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (1, 238, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 453, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (2, 319, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 463, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (3, 400, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'C', N'C', N'C', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'M', N'C', N'C', NULL, N'C', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'C', NULL, NULL, N'City', 635, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (4, 481, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', N'N', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 947, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (5, 561, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'C', N'C', N'M', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'C', N'C', NULL, N'C', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'C', NULL, NULL, N'City', 1005, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (6, 640, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'M', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, N'C', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'C', N'N', NULL, N'City', 1111, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (7, 955, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 1643, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (8, 1035, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'M', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, N'H', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'H', N'S', NULL, N'Headquarter', 1926, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (9, 1115, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'B', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'B', N'B', N'B', N'M', N'B', N'B', N'B', N'B', NULL, N'B', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'B', NULL, NULL, N'Switchboard', 2222, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (10, 1196, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', N'N', N'N', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 3333, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (11, 1276, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', N'H', NULL, N'County', 4022, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (12, 1355, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 4043, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (13, 1433, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'C', N'C', N'M', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'C', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'C', N'C', NULL, N'C', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'C', NULL, NULL, N'City', 4075, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (14, 1820, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, NULL, NULL, N'M', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'Unknown', 4444, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (15, 1900, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, NULL, NULL, N'M', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'Unknown', 5555, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (16, 1980, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'M', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, N'T', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'T', N'Z', NULL, N'Unknown', 7003, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (17, 2060, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 7006, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (18, 2139, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'M', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'H', N'', N'', NULL, N'H', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'H', N'S', NULL, N'Headquarter', 7007, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (19, 2217, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'N', N'N', N'M', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'N', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'N', N'N', NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'N', NULL, NULL, N'County', 7012, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (20, 2294, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'T', N'T', N'M', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'T', N'T', NULL, N'T', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'T', N'T', NULL, N'Unknown', 7020, NULL, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] ([DD_ID], [A_ID], [DD_Date], [H0], [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], [H7], [H8], [H9], [H10], [H11], [H12], [H13], [H14], [H15], [H16], [H17], [H18], [H19], [H20], [H21], [H22], [H23], [H24], [AllocatedBlock], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [Comments], [Overtime], [PBlock], [SBlock], [TBlock], [BlockName], [DD_UserID], [Std_Start], [STd_End]) VALUES (21, 2605, CAST(0x22380B00 AS Date), N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'M', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'T', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', NULL, N'T', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'T', N'T', NULL, N'Unknown', 7039, NULL, NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_DutyDetails] OFF
```

The table had to be structured this way. I would like to achieve an output like this:

```
           Letter   H0  H1 H2 H3  H4  H5  H6....
04/02/2014 C       123 456 33 22 111 223 555....
04/02/2014 T        44  56 56 33 556 566 333....
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789225/number-of-times-a-particular-character-appears-in-a-string

Comment: This question has no relevance to the 'duplicate', I am counting fields which contains certain charcters

Comment: you want to know how many rows in each column had that value or something else? Also specify SQL platform that you are using.

Comment: Exactly that, in the example output that would mean that the letter 'C' was in field H5 223 times on the 4th of Feb. Platform is SQL 2008 R2