# Finding out the number of character differences between two string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string

I am looking for some **built-in** function which is able to find out in how many character two string differ.

For example:

```
CharDiff('SO0035F', 'SO005F') = 1

CharDiff('12345', '34512') = 0
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no built-in function for that in sql-server or it would be listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms181984.aspx but it should not be too hard to write your own function for that, besides that, what would be your expected result for example for `CharDiff('SO0035F', 'SO035F')` (0 exists in both strings but the count of it varies) should this also return 1?

Comment: Yes, I see that it was not clearly written, I think I should write my own function for this. The answer of your question is that it should check not only the existance of the character in the other string but that how many times it apperas it also matters.

Comment: What result do you expect when comparing 'ab' and 'cde'?

Comment: I expect 5, but now it is clear that it can't be solved without wrinting my own function.

Comment: @jannagy02 as you wrote your last comment after my answer, did you consider my answer?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Of course, but if you read my question again, I emphasized that BUILT-IN. But I will probably get back to this question in some days, please be patient if it help me, I will accept :)

Answer (score 4):

I needed something slightly different.  I needed a comparison of '1234' to show as 2 characters different than '1243' even though they contain the same characters.

I came up with the following:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CharDiff (@string1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @string2 NVARCHAR(MAX))
 RETURNS INT
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @diffs INT = 0
     WHILE LEN(@string1) > 0 AND LEN(@string2) > 0
     BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@string1,1,1) <> SUBSTRING(@string2,1,1)
            SELECT @diffs = @diffs + 1
        SELECT @string1 = SUBSTRING(@string1,2,9999)
        SELECT @string2 = SUBSTRING(@string2,2,9999)
     END
     RETURN @diffs + LEN(@string1) + LEN(@string2)
 END
```

Answer (score 2):

As [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms181984.aspx) lists all string functions available in SQL Server, I am pretty sure there is no built-in functionality for exactly this use case available.

However, with a little help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789266/2186023) I came up with the following which seems to fit your needs:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CharDiff (@string1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @string2 NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @allDifferences INT = 0
    DECLARE @charCount1 INT
    DECLARE @charCount2 INT

    --do this as long as both strings are longer than 0
    WHILE LEN(@string1) > 0 AND LEN(@string2) > 0
    BEGIN
        --get char count for the character at index 1 in string 1
        SELECT @charCount1 = (LEN(@string1) - LEN(REPLACE(@string1, SUBSTRING(@string1, 1, 1), '')))
        --get char count for the character at index 1 in string 1 but for string2
        SELECT @charCount2 = (LEN(@string2) - LEN(REPLACE(@string2, SUBSTRING(@string1, 1, 1), '')))

        --strip all chars that now have been counted from string 2
        SELECT @string2 = REPLACE(@string2, SUBSTRING(@string1, 1, 1),'')
        --strip all chars that now have been counted from string 1
        SELECT @string1 = REPLACE(@string1, SUBSTRING(@string1, 1, 1),'')

        --add difference to counting variable
        SELECT @allDifferences = @allDifferences + ABS(@charCount1 - @charCount2)
    END

    --is there any rest length on any of those string?
    SELECT @allDifferences = @allDifferences + ABS(LEN(@string1) - LEN(@string2))


    RETURN @allDifferences
END
```

Basically I just count the occurence of the character that currently exists on index 1 in the first string in both strings.
Then I delete all those already counted characters from both strings (that way index 1 holds another character each iteration), as long as both strings have any characters in them. The rest length of a string that might still exist after that loop can simply be added to `@allDifferences`.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the answer of [Scott R. Frost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931634). This solution shows a comparison of '1234' to '1243' as 2 characters different even though they contain the same characters.

For strings up to 8 characters long:

```
SELECT
    LEN(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),
                        CONVERT(binary(8),
                                CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(binary(8), String1)) ^ CONVERT(binary(8), String2)
                                )
                        ) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
                char(0),
                '')) AS XORCharDiff
FROM (VALUES ('Example1', 'Example2')) AS X(String1, String2)
```

For all string lengths:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.XORCharDiff (@string1 VARCHAR(MAX), @string2 VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @diffs INT = 0
    WHILE LEN(@string1) > 0 AND LEN(@string2) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @diffs = @diffs +
                LEN(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),
                        CONVERT(binary(8),
                                CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(binary(8), SUBSTRING(@string1, 1, 8))) ^ CONVERT(binary(8),  SUBSTRING(@string2, 1, 8))
                                )
                            ) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
                    char(0),
                    ''))
        SELECT @string1 = SUBSTRING(@string1,9,8)
        SELECT @string2 = SUBSTRING(@string2,9,8)
    END
    RETURN @diffs + LEN(@string1) + LEN(@string2)
END
```

The string comparison is based on a bitwise XOR of binary representations of both strings.
In case of matching characters in the two strings, the characters 'cancel each other  out' resulting in a 0x00/char(0)

Example:
01001000 01101001 'Hi' (String1)
01001000 01100001 'Ha' (String2)
00000000 00001000 resulting bitwise XOR

By removing the char(0), the length of string is reduced by the number of matching characters.

It can all be done as in a single line without the need of a loop and a function. Which results in a high speed solution.

Some further explanation:
The `Bigint` conversion is needed since bitwise XOR does not work on 2 binaries. Because Bigint has 8 Bytes, this sets the limit to 8 characters per comparison.
`COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` is needed because otherwise unprintable characters are removed.

See below the timing comparison between this solution and [CharDiff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931634)  function (for 100k of 8 character long strings).

```
XOR CharDiff (single line max 8 characters)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 110 ms,  elapsed time = 109 ms.

(100000 rows affected)

XOR CharDiff function (all string lengths)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3188 ms,  elapsed time = 3979 ms.

(100000 rows affected)

CharDiff
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 7828 ms,  elapsed time = 10442 ms.

(100000 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more set based version of [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931634/73226) is

```
DECLARE @String1 VARCHAR(10) = '1234', 
        @String2 VARCHAR(10) = '1243'


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, GREATEST(LEN(@String1 + 'X'), LEN(@String2 + 'X')) - 1)
WHERE SUBSTRING(@String1, value, 1) <>  SUBSTRING(@String2, value, 1)
```

This requires [SQL Server 2022+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

The same approach of splitting the string into characters with `GENERATE_SERIES` can also be used as a first step for different definitions of `CharDiff`