# Count a word inside a long string in c#

Tags: c#, string, search, count, cpu-word

Can you please explain me how do i find in a simple way the number of times that a certain string occurs inside a big string?
Example:

```
  string longString = "hello1 hello2 hello546 helloasdf";
```

The word "hello" is there four times. how can i get the number four.
Thanks

EDIT: I would like to know how i find a two word string as well for example:

```
 string longString = "hello there hello2 hello4 helloas hello there";
```

I want to know the number of occurrences of "hello there".

EDIT 2: The regex method was the best for me (with the counts) but it does not find a word like this for example: ">word<" . Somehow, if I want to search for a word containing "<>" it skips it. Help?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: So you need to compare the "word" as well as "partial word", but what have you tried ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string

Comment: I covered this for SQL here: the same method would be fine (and not require regex!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789225/number-of-times-a-particular-character-appears-in-a-string/9789266#9789266

Answer (score 3):

just use `string.Split()` and count the results:

```
string wordToFind = "hello";

string longString = "hello1 hello2 hello546 helloasdf";
int occurences = longString
                     .Split(new []{wordToFind}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                     .Count() - 1;

//occurences = 4
```

to answer your edit, just change `wordToFind` to `hello there`

Answer (score 1):

```
string longString = "hello1 hello2 hello546 helloasdf";
var regex = new Regex("hello");

var matches = regex.Matches(longString);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
```

Comment: Hi, this was the best method for me but when i want a word that contains ">word<" it doesn't find it when it exists. it skips <> please help. thx

Answer (score 0):

to do this with LINQ:

```
int count = 
    longString.Split(' ')
    .Count(str => str
    .Contains("hello", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

The only assumption here is that your longString is delimited by a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Linq to do this.

```
string longString = "hello1 hello2 hello546 helloasdf";
string target = "hello";
var count = longString.Split(' ').ToList<string>().Count(w => w.Contains(target));
Console.WriteLine(count);
```