# Counting for specific characters in a row - SQL

Tags: sql

I'm looking to see if it's possible to only display results with multiple instances of a single character.  For instance, if I wanted to only show rows that have the "," character in it more than 6 times.

Example:  I, am, trying, to, figure, out, this, query

Would show in the results, but any row with less than 6 ","'s wouldn't show.

Comment: Please tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of times a particular character appears in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789225/number-of-times-a-particular-character-appears-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `length` and `replace` to show strings that have `,` 6 or more times:

```
select * from mytable where length(mycolumn) - length(replace(mycolumn, ",", "")) >= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where col like '%,%,%,%,%,%,%';
```

This should work in any database.