# SQL - trying to find a set of data which only has a certain set of values but not anything else in a few columns

Tags: sql-server

Hopefully an easy problem for an experienced SQL person. I have an application which uses SQL Server, and I cannot perform this query in the application, so I'm hoping to back-door it, but I need help.

I have a table with a large list of emails and all its metadata. I'm trying to find email that is only between parties of this one company and flag them.

What I did was search where `companyName.com` is in `To` and `From` and marked a `TagField` as `1` (I did this through my application's front end).

Now what I need to do is search where any other possible values, ignoring `companyName.com` exist in `To` and `From` where I've already flagged them as 1 in `TagField`. `From` will usually just have one value, but `To` could have multiple, all formatted differently, but all separated by a semi-colon (I will probably have to apply this same search to CC and BCC columns, too).

Any thoughts?

Comment: will be very helpful if you put samples and expected result in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ; with the empty string.  Then check to see if the length changed.  If there's one email address, there shouldn't be a ';'.  You could also use the same technique to replace the company name with the empty string.  Anything left would be the other companies.

```
select email_id, to_email
from yourtable
where TagField = 1 and len(to_email) <> len(replace(to_email,';',''))
```

This solution is based on the following thread

[Number of times a particular character appears in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789225/number-of-times-a-particular-character-appears-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

So I went an entirely different route and exported my data to a CSV and used Python to get to where I needed.  Here's the code I used in case anybody needs it.  What this returned for me was a list of DocIDs (unique identifiers that were in the CSV) where ever there was an email address in the To field that wasn't from one specific domain.  I went into the original CSV and made sure all instances of this domain name were in all lowercase, too.

```
    import csv
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    sub = "domainname"

    def findMultipleTo(dict):
        for row in reader:
            if row['To'].find(";") != -1:
                toArray = row['To'].split(';')
                newTo = [s for s in toArray if sub not in s]
                row['To'] = newTo
            else:
                row['To'] = 'empty'

            with open('location\\newCSV-BCCFieldSearch.csv', 'a') as f:
                if row['To'] != "empty" and row['To'] != []:
                    print(row['DocID'], row['To'], file = f)
                else:
                    pass


    with open(file_path) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)    

        findMultipleTo(reader)
```