# Find Number of times a particular character appears in a string using MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular, find-occurrences, mdx-query

In the Microsoft SSAS, I have a dimension column that contains multiple values separated by the special character `|` in a single row as below.

**Example value of a row:** `Image|Video|Audio|`

**Requirement:**
So, I need to count the number of values present in the dimension column using the special character.

In this case, I need to get the count of `|` using the MDX query and my expected answer is 3.

Could someone help me with this? In short, Is there an MDX function that counts the number of times a particular character appears in a string?

Similar question for SQL: [Number of times a particular character appears in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789225/number-of-times-a-particular-character-appears-in-a-string)

Comment: Do it in sql and include it in the cube for exploration.

Comment: I agree with @mxix that this is easier to do when you load the table. If you had to do in MDX, try a recursive measure with Instr(). See link for recursive example:  http://mdxdax.blogspot.com/2011/04/performance-considerations-for.html